# Missing joint trajectory controller

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I'm using ros melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and when I try to make my workspace with catkin_make I get the following error message:

```
 CMake Error at /opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "joint_trajectory_controller" with any of the following names:

    joint_trajectory_controllerConfig.cmake
    joint_trajectory_controller-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "joint_trajectory_controller" to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "joint_trajectory_controller_DIR" to a directory
  containing one of the above files.  If "joint_trajectory_controller"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/ur_controllers/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/bodon/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/bodon/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

And when I type the following command in a different but sourced terminal I get another error message:

```
command:  sudo apt-get install joint_trajectory_controller
error: E: Unable to locate package joint_trajectory_controller
```

Could please help me with this?

gvdhoorn thank you for your help!  http://answers.ros.org/question/325039/ this link solved my problem. Have a nice day, thanks again!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338321/missing-joint-trajectory-controller/) by [bodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49654/bodi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-11-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-25**:\

> gvdhoorn thank you for your help! http://answers.ros.org/question/325039/ this link solved my problem. Have a nice day, thanks again!

and this would be something for which it is perfectly fine to post it in a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm using ros melodic on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and when I try to make my workspace with catkin_make

Have you made sure to install all dependencies before doing that?

Please refer to #q252478 for a possible workflow.

And to avoid an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info): can you explain why you are building the `joint_trajectory_controller` from source on `bionic`?

---

Edit:

> I followed this tutorial for UR robots: https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver

If with "this tutorial" you mean the steps listed in the [Building](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/0bec493abd41a68dd3b9c580374a6c681d46b75e/README.md#building) section of the [README](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/0bec493abd41a68dd3b9c580374a6c681d46b75e/README.md), then those would seem to already include the `rosdep install ..` command described in #q252478.

Did you run those commands? Did they successfully complete? If not: what was the error output?

> And I got the error when I tried to run catkin_make.

If dependencies have not been installed, you'll receive the error message you show.

> About the xy_problem you're right. I tried to solve my first problem with that, following my friend's advice.

**Always** prefer to use binary packages over building things from source. Do *not* simply "build a package from source" if you run into the CMake error you show. That should be the absolute last resort.

I cannot repeat this often enough.  Please also tell your friend.

There are few exceptions, some of which are described here: #q320046.

Finally: if there are problems with the installation and setup guide of `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver`, you should report those on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/issues).

---

Edit 2:

> Following the Building, I get this error message after

> ```
> $ sudo apt update -qq
> ```

> ```
> 450 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
> ```

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

> ```
> W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
> W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
> ```

> Btw, I get other errors for the rosdep install line

You are using a machine (or a container) that has either not setup the ROS package repositories correctly, or is running into #q325039.

Note how the readme of `Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver` states:

> This driver requires a system setup with ROS

So you'll have to make sure that has been done before following the instructions in the readme.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49654/bodi/) on 2019-11-22**:
I followed this tutorial for UR robots:

https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver

And I got the error when I tried to run catkin_make.

About the xy_problem you're right. I tried to solve my first problem with that, following my friend's advice.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-22**:
Just for completeness: what is the output of the following commands:

```
lsb_release -a
uname -rvmp
```

**Comment by [bodi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49654/bodi/) on 2019-11-25**:
Following the Building, I get this error message after

```
$ sudo apt update -qq

450 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Btw, I get other errors for the rosdep install line

Thanks again for your help!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-11-25**:
Also: please don't post this sort of output in a comment. They do not allow for sufficient lines of text, so please edit your original question text and append the new information.

Use the `edit` button/link for that.